# Android Send Notifications to all the users using Messaging API (ARC)

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have followed [this](http://androidbash.com/firebase-push-notification-android/) tutorial to achieve my target (i.e - `Send push notifications` to *all the users* (devices) with image and text) no matter app in *foreground or background*.

What I learnt, If we are sending *using Messaging API (ARC - Advanced REST Client)* then user would get Notification with *Image and Text* both either app is in `foreground or background`.

But I don't know How Can I send *Notifications to all the devices/users* using `Messaging API (ARC)` ?

I used **below** script to send Notification *to single user* only:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIza************adrTY

{ "data": {
    "image": "https://ibin.co/2t1lLdpfS06F.png",
    "message": "Firebase Push Message Using API"
    "AnotherActivity": "True"
  },
  "to" : "f25gYF3***********************HLI"
}
```

If, I would not be able to send *Notifications to all the users* using `Messaging API (ARC)` then it'll be good waste of time for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way subscribe all user to one topic and send to the topic.

Like this:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("all");
```

And send notification like that:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIza************adrTY

{ "data": {
    "image": "https://ibin.co/2t1lLdpfS06F.png",
    "message": "Firebase Push Message Using API"
    "AnotherActivity": "True"
  },
  "to" : "/topics/all"
}
```

Comment: I have already trid with  "to": "/topics/news" but I did not get the notification, as you can see I am using this line: FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news"); in my code within MainActivity...

Comment: sorry I have not noticed, due to slow internet network, I did not receive Notification that time, I just sent again and found that I am getting... anyways thanks for prompt reply and help...after next 2 minutes I'll accept your answer...

Comment: No problem :) any question just ask @Sophie

Comment: Cheers. Accepted and tapped as useful... In Notification Bar, I am just getting "message" content in place of Title, whereas I want to show both Title and Message in my Notification... please check this: https://pastebin.com/Vdt4ZaF7 and let me know what can I try to get my target...

Comment: Probably you need to get data and create notification in onMessageRecived()

Comment: Just Add Comma after "message": "Firebase Push Message Using API"